# How do I stagger launch of objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-3.10

I am attempting to make a game where there are multiple objects falling that you have to avoid, each at different altitudes. However, I ended up with just 8 blocks at the top and 1 falling at a time. Could someone please help me understand why and fix it? I suspect something with indentation.

The code is below.

````
import pygame
import random
import sys
import time
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

#some config

print(os.getcwd())

pygame.init()

#actually runs the game

def game():
    print("")
    WIDTH = 800
    HEIGHT = 600

    TRASH = (110, 110, 110)
    SEA_TURTLE = (108,170,180)
    player_pos = [400, 475]
    player_size = 50
    game_over = False
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    my_image = pygame.image.load("SeaTurtle1.png").convert_alpha()
    enemy_size = 40

    SPEED = 11

    FPS = 120

    enemy_pos = [random.randint(0, WIDTH - enemy_size), 0]
    enemy_list = [enemy_pos]

    score = 0

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    myFont = pygame.font.SysFont("DroidSans", 35)

    pygame.display.set_caption('Trash Dodge, Science Project,  By: Benjamin Bernstein')

    pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)

#drops enemies mechanic

    def drop_enemies(enemy_list):
        if len(enemy_list) < 9:
            x_pos = random.randint(0, WIDTH - enemy_size)
            y_pos = 10
            enemy_list.append([x_pos, y_pos])

#make enemies

    def draw_enemies(enemy_list):
        for enemy_pos in enemy_list:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, TRASH, (enemy_pos[0], enemy_pos[1], enemy_size, enemy_size))

#update enemies kinda broken ngl

    def update_enemies_pos(enemy_list, score):
        for idx, enemy_pos in enumerate(enemy_list):
            if enemy_pos[1] >= 0 and enemy_pos[1] < HEIGHT:
                enemy_pos[1] += SPEED
            else:
                enemy_list.pop(idx)
                score += 1
            return score

#collision detection

    def collision_check(enemy_list, player_pos):
        for enemy_pos in enemy_list:
            if detect_collision(enemy_pos, player_pos):
                return True
            return False

#edge detection so you can teleport to other side of window

    def edge_detection1(player_pos):
        if player_pos[0] > 750:
            return True
        return False

    def edge_detection2(player_pos):
        if player_pos[0] < 0:
            return True
        return False

#more collision detection

    def detect_collision(player_pos, enemy_pos):
        p_x = player_pos[0]
        p_y = player_pos[1]

        e_x = enemy_pos[0]
        e_y = enemy_pos[1]

        if (e_x >= p_x and e_x < (p_x + player_size)) or (p_x >= e_x and p_x < (e_x + enemy_size)):
            if (e_y >= p_y and e_y < (p_y + player_size)) or (p_y >= e_y and p_y < (e_y + enemy_size)):
                return True
            return False

#some stuff to run all the time like controls, score and window

    while not game_over:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                x = player_pos[0]
                y = player_pos[1]
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x -= player_size
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x += player_size
                elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    x -= player_size
                elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    x += player_size
                elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    x -= player_size
                elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    sys.exit()

                player_pos = [x, y]
        screen.fill((108,170,180))

        drop_enemies(enemy_list)
        score = update_enemies_pos(enemy_list, score)

        text = "Score: " + str(score)
        label = myFont.render(text, 1, (0, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(label, (WIDTH - 120, HEIGHT - 40))
#HERE IT IS
#MORE EDGE DETECTION THIS MAKES ME GO INSANE

        if edge_detection1(player_pos):
            player_pos[0] = 0

        if edge_detection2(player_pos):
            player_pos[0] = 750

        if collision_check(enemy_list, player_pos):
            time.sleep(1.4)
            Tk().wm_withdraw()
            game_over = True
        draw_enemies(enemy_list)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, SEA_TURTLE, (player_pos[0], player_pos[1], player_size, player_size))
        player = pygame.draw.rect(screen, SEA_TURTLE, (player_pos[0], player_pos[1], player_size, player_size))
        screen.blit(my_image, player)
        clock.tick(FPS)
        pygame.display.update()
#death message
    ans = messagebox.askretrycancel("You died.", "You lose! This game shows how hard litter and trash makes it for sea turtles to survive. Make sure to pick up any litter and trash you see on the beach.")
    root = Tk()
    root.destroy()
    return ans

#close the game

while True:
    if game() == True:
        pass
    else:
        break```
````

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the indentation is the problem. You are returning inside the loop in the `update_enemies_pos` function.
This should work:

```
def update_enemies_pos(enemy_list, score):
    for idx, enemy_pos in enumerate(enemy_list):
        if enemy_pos[1] >= 0 and enemy_pos[1] < HEIGHT:
            enemy_pos[1] += SPEED
        else:
            enemy_list.pop(idx)
            score += 1
    return score
```